# Postfix: SSL_accept:error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A

Tags: ssl, postfix

A couple weeks ago, I noticed the following lines in my logs after moving to a new server with up-to-date software (which, among others, allowed me to finally disable deprecated SSL/TLS versions):

```
Apr 18 13:31:24 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: connect from relay2.uni-heidelberg.de[129.206.119.212]
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: setting up TLS connection from relay2.uni-heidelberg.de[129.206.119.212]
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: relay2.uni-heidelberg.de[129.206.119.212]: TLS cipher list "AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH"
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: SSL_accept:error in SSLv2/v3 read client hello A
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: SSL_accept error from relay2.uni-heidelberg.de[129.206.119.212]: -1
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:650:
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: lost connection after STARTTLS from relay2.uni-heidelberg.de[129.206.119.212]
Apr 18 13:31:25 myhostname postfix/smtpd[1641]: disconnect from relay2.uni-heidelberg.de[129.206.119.212]
```

These lines have kept repeating ever since. However, emails from other mail servers (Gmail among others) have gotten through, so it seemed this issue was restricted to this particular client. But today I noticed similar log messages when the Amazon and Facebook mail servers connected. (Though, interestingly, they immediately reconnect afterwards – sometimes from a different host – and then it works.)

Is there anything I could do to fix these issues or to allow the emails to be delivered?

I'm running Postfix 2.11.3.

Output of `$ postconf -n`:

```
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_process_limit = 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
enable_original_recipient = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 52428800
mydestination = *****, localhost
myhostname = *****
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
queue_minfree = 0
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_loglevel = 2
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:localhost:10023
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = ******
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong
smtpd_tls_key_file = ******
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
tls_medium_cipherlist = AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:994
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 1073741824
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domainaliases_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:994
```

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, HBruijn: Thanks for your answers! I changed a couple settings following your suggestions and am still waiting to see what effect they have. Once I do, I will accept the answer that worked for me. (Admittedly, this is quite subjective which is why I already upvoted both of your answers.)

Answer (score 3):

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
...
tls_medium_cipherlist = AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
```

You have overly restrictive settings by restricting the protocol to TLS 1.2 only. A major part of the mail servers uses some kind of UNIX with OpenSSL as the TLS library. Support for TLS 1.2 was only added with version 1.0.1 which was released about 4 years ago. This means that there are lots of servers which use an older version of OpenSSL and which thus cannot fail to connect to your server with TLS. Depending on the peers server setup and software this means that mail delivery to your system will either fail permanently or that it will retry without TLS.

Thus in case of mail transfer you should be less restrictive and accept at least TLS 1.0 and maybe even SSL 3.0, because bad encryption is in most cases better then no encryption or even than no delivery. The same is true for the cipher set: while preference of stronger ciphers is fine you should also include some non-DH ciphers and some just strong enough ciphers like DES-CBC3-SHA to you cipher set.

Answer (score 1):

You have configurered Postfix to use strong crypto with the recommended TLS security settings such as found on https://cipherli.st/

By only accepting two strong ciphers with the security settings `smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium` and 
`tls_medium_cipherlist = AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH` and only allowing  TLS 1.2 you have traded off security over compatibility.

relay2.uni-heidelberg.de is willing to negotiate and switch over to an encrypted connection but can't negotiate a suitable cipher. And although the setting [`smtpd_tls_security_level = may`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_security_level) allows your server the fall-back to an unencrypted clear-text connection, apparently relay2 is not willing to fallback.

Either you need to support some weaker ciphers as well, or relay2 needs to be upgraded to support modern strong ciphers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it could be because of your mail client application. For example in Outlook you need to set its encryption from Auto to SSL explicitly in the settings of outgoing smtp server to get it working.
Hope it helps